# Spotify Web API OAuth Error 400: Error using Axios and Async/Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, spotify

I want to use the Spotify Web API, and I'm using the **authorization_code** example from their their [web-api-auth-examples repository](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples).

I wanted to use the axios library (with async/await) instead of the request library since request was deprecated earlier this year.

So I tried modifying the `app.get()` method for the `/callback` route, but I'm getting a 400 error (Bad Request) from my `getAuth()` function in the post request.

Been stuck on this one for several hours now and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

app.js:

```
const express = require('express'); 
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });

const client_id = `${process.env.CLIENT_ID}`;
const client_secret = `${process.env.CLIENT_SECRET}`;
const redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback';
 
...
const app = express();
...

app.get('/callback', function (req, res) {
  const code = req.query.code || null;
  const state = req.query.state || null;
  const storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;

  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
    res.redirect(
      '/#' +
        querystring.stringify({
          error: 'state_mismatch',
        })
    );
  } else {
    res.clearCookie(stateKey);

    const postHeaders = {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(
        `${client_id}:${client_secret}`
      ).toString('base64')}`,
    };

    const postStringHeaders = querystring.stringify(postHeaders);

    const getAuth = async () => {
      try {
        let response = await axios({
          url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
          method: 'post',
          params: {
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            code,
            redirect_uri,
          },
          postStringHeaders,
        });

        if (response.status === 200) {
          const access_token = response.data.access_token;
          const refresh_token = response.data.refresh_token;
          const getUrl = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me';

          const getHeaders = {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
          };

          const getStringHeaders = querystring.stringify(getHeaders);

          try {
            let getRes = await axios({
              method: 'get',
              getUrl,
              getStringHeaders,
              params: {
                access_token,
                refresh_token,
              },
            });

            if (getRes.status === 200) {
              console.log(body);
            }

            res.redirect(
              '/#' +
                querystring.stringify({
                  access_token: access_token,
                  refresh_token: refresh_token,
                })
            );
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        } else {
          res.redirect(
            '/#' +
              querystring.stringify({
                error: 'invalid_token',
              })
          );
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    getAuth();
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is the exact error, there are two calls to spotify ? Are you able to get the access_token?

Comment: The error is in the response to the axios post request (the first call to the spotify API). I was able to get the access_token before when I used the original template which used the request library, so I know my client_id and client_secret variables are working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the requests to succeed by modifying my code for the `app.get()` method as shown below!

```
app.get('/callback', async function (req, res) {
  const code = req.query.code || null;
  const state = req.query.state || null;
  const storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;

  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
    res.redirect(
      '/#' +
        querystring.stringify({
          error: 'state_mismatch',
        })
    );
  } else {
    res.clearCookie(stateKey);

    const postHeaders = {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    };

    try {
      let response = await axios({
        url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        method: 'post',
        params: {
          client_id,
          client_secret,
          grant_type: 'authorization_code',
          code,
          redirect_uri,
        },
        postHeaders,
      });

      if (response.status === 200) {
        const access_token = response.data.access_token;
        const refresh_token = response.data.refresh_token;
        const getUrl = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me';

        const getHeaders = {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        };

        try {
          let getRes = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: getUrl,
            getHeaders,
            params: {
              access_token,
              refresh_token,
            },
          });

          if (getRes.status === 200) {
            console.log('LOGIN SUCCESSFUL!', getRes.data);
          }

          res.redirect(
            '/#' +
              querystring.stringify({
                access_token: access_token,
                refresh_token: refresh_token,
              })
          );
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      } else {
        res.redirect(
          '/#' +
            querystring.stringify({
              error: 'invalid_token',
            })
        );
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response);
    }
  }
});
```